# How to open a PHP/form results page in a new window?

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

I have a form:

```
<form action="bar.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="foo" value="<?php SOME_STUFF(); ?>" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

which acts on a PHP script that generates a PDF from the form contents:

```
/* bar.php */
<?php
  $html = $_POST['foo'];
  $pdf->$writeHTML($html);
  $pdf->Output('bar.pdf');
?>
```

And my client would like this to open in a new window. I know HTML won't validate a `target` attribute for a form, so must I use JavaScript? And, where?

Comment: HTML won't validate? What's this?

Comment: The "target" attribute is not valid in XHTML Strict.

Comment: Sorry, HTML Strict [won't validate](http://24ways.org/2005/transitional-vs-strict-markup) a target attribute. I'm not DTD'ing Strict so it doesn't matter. I had the same reaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to insert target="_blank" into form tag

and read this http://www.tufat.com/script19.htm about output to pdf